# Print Chinese / Japanese character in Zebra Printer with ZPL

Tags: unicode, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I have loaded the Mono Chinese/ Japanese font onto my ZM400 printer. So far I have no success printing both Chinese & English together on the same field.

Here is some example code:

```
^XA^CW1,B:ANMDS.TTF
^SEB:GB.DAT^CI14
^FO100,100^A1,50,50^FD中文English Here^FS
^XZ
```

Since I change the international code to 14 (with ^CI14), it only prints the Chinese text without the English text.

I have also try using the ^FL command, but can't seen to get it to work.

Does anyone have a working example of printing Chinese / Japanese text along with English text on the same FD (data field)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured out why. The Chinese text needs to be in gibberish format.

What I meant by gibberish is that. When you use Chinese in ZPL code, it needs to be in the windows codepage format text. This windows codepage format Text that is Chinese will be displayed as gibberish in English environment.

For example. In ZPL Code, your code might look like this:
^H ~!!#@#@$  (this gibberish is actual the ASCII representation of Chinese text in windows code page format)

However, you can't type in unicode Chinese because ZPL would not print it.
^H 中文  (this is Chinese text in unicode format)

Comment: Literally, the gibberish meaning the windows codepage text that is in gibberish form.

Comment: "Gibberish" means nothing to the people looking at this, why not update your question/answer with what you actually ended up with.

Comment: Edited the answer to make it better. You guys misunderstood my meaning of gibberish since it looks like it's a problem that not many people familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use ^CI28 (UTF-8), and make sure that your labels are encoded in UTF-8.

As far as I know, ^CI14 only supports Asian encodings.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking at how to do this, I imagine what I did for Japanese will work for Chinese.

Firstly, I didn't want to purchase the Asian Font Pack because I think it's a bit of a ripoff, so I found an appropriate open source Japanese Unitype Font. I then uploaded this to the printer using Zebra Tools... make sure you upload it as a file, NOT using the font upload.

Then I managed to get it printing by escaping the characters.

So my final ZPL is

```
^XA
^LL150
^CI28^A@N,60,60,E:OSAKA.TTF
^FO0,0
^FH
^FD_5F_E3_81_93_E3_82_8C_E3_81_AF_E4_BD_95_E3_81_A8_E8_A8_80_E3_81_A3_E3_81_A6_E3_81_84_E3_81_BE_E3_81_99^FS
^XZ
```

Essentially you have to escape the bytes of each value (original Japanese これは何と言っています)

You also have to put ^FH in front of ^FD so it knows you're escaping characters.

Hopefully this helps the poster and anyone else who is looking to overcome problems with ZPL and Unicode fonts / characters.

Comment: HI @DoctorDbx, I tried to use your method, but it is not working, I have simsun.TTF installed, but what is printed out is the hex code. I put the SIMSUN.TFF as well. you got any insight on this ?